# android: shrink the font size of android emulator

Tags: android, emulation

The font size showing on my android 2.33 emulator is quite big. I've tried other version of android emulator and same thing happened. Is there any configuration within the emulator to set a smaller font size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to your AVD manager in eclipse and start the emulator manually, a launch window will pop up. Within that window, check in the box beside 'Scale display to real size' and enter a custom screen size, that should shrink down the emulator size (thereby reducing the fonts?)

Also, try playing around with the AVD density settings. Both of these methods gave me a significantly different looking emulator.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have asked permission manually. Choose from standard , for example: WQVGA 400

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since you've posted the issue, but I am leaving my experience below for further cases.
First of all it'd be good to bear in mind, that the emulator behaves just like the real device, thus they have the same setting properties as the real ones.
Start up your emulator and swipe to the Settings, then go to Display sub menu -> find Font size or/and Display size depending on what you want to achieve *(they could be located in the "Advanced" option)*.

Note:- Android Emulator development has evolved since 2011. Current versions of Emulator are very much similar to actual android device.